# emulate List<byte[]> in java1.4

Tags: java

I need to adopt code that was created using java 1.6 for java 1.4 JVM.
What is the best way to change generics usage that is missing in java 1.4? Actually I need to change only this expression:

```
 List<byte[]>
```

Comment: As generics were introduced with Java 1.5 all you can do in Java 1.4 is to use the raw type `List`.

Comment: You could try something like [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) or [retrotranslator](http://retrotranslator.sourceforge.net/) to make this thing easier in general. (Out of curiosity: who uses Java 1.4 anymore? I'd have thought even banks have moved on by now.)

Comment: @millimoose: lol, banks :D We're talking Fortran95 here!

Comment: @jlordo Thank god for my carefully maintained bubble of non-enterprisey modernity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that Java 1.4 has no generics, the only thing you can do is use the [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) here

```
List myByteList = new ArrayList();
byte[] myByteArray1 = ...
myByteList.add(myByteArray1);
// add more byte arrays ...
```

To retrieve, casting is required, e.g.

```
byte[] myByteArray = (byte[])myByteList.get(0);
```

Now you see the main benefit that generics bring ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generic is not available in java 1.4, so you can not use any type with `List`. You bound to use `raw type List`.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
byte[] byteArray = ...
list.add(byteArray);
```

Note: *you can add any type of Object to this raw list.*